# implementing batch process on a select statement

Tags: java, sql, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I am executing two select queries. The result of first select query is used to get the result of second select query.
Example 
query 1 = "Select name, accountNumber from table 1"
query 2 = "Select budget_column1, budget_column2 from table2 where column3 = accountNumber which we got from select query1;

I'm trying to optimize my code . It is taking very long time to display results.
How to implement prepared Statement addbatch in this kind o scenario. I have been searching but most of the examples show for insert, update , delete statement not on select statement

Comment: There is not an `addBatch` method on java.sql.ResultSet. Are you thinking of `PreparedStatement.addBatch` and the corresponding `executeBatch`?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch--    http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch--

Answer (score 1):

Try combining the queries into a single query (join) and let the RDBMS optimize if needed:

```
select t1.name, t2.budget_column1, t2.budget_column2
from table1 as t1, table2 as t2
where t1.accountNumber = t2.column3;
```

Comment: Actually there are other things going on in the code. I cannot use joins

Comment: Is there any other way to accomplish this by using the addbatch of resultset or by using prepared statement

Comment: Perhaps put an index on column3 in table2 to make the accountNumber matching quicker.

Comment: Oh, with addbatch.  Never used it.  As for prepared statement, it should have no impact on server-side execution efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

The batch execution is only for modify statements (insert, update, delete), not for select.

Generally your best option is to allow the database to do joins for you and execute as few statements as possible. If you truly do need to execute 2 different queries, you will need to make sure you have indexed access to provide good performance.